# handling arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm new to javascript and react
I have an array of data as follows

```
const data = [
    {
        folder_name: "folder 002",
        file_name: "anh 1.jpg"
    },
    {
        folder_name: "folder 002",
        file_name: "anh 2.jpg"
    },
    {
        folder_name: "folder 002",
        file_name: "anh 3.jpg"
    },
    {
        folder_name: "folder 002",
        file_name: "anh 4.jpg"
    },
    {
        folder_name: "folder 001",
        file_name: "anh 1.jpg"
    },
    {
        folder_name: "folder 001",
        file_name: "anh 2.jpg"
    },
    {
        folder_name: "folder 001",
        file_name: "anh 3.jpg"
    }
]
```

Please help me split into array like this.
Please help me to return the array like this
The result I wanted

```
const images = [
    {
        folder_name: 'folder 001',
        file_name: ['anh 1','anh 2','anh 3']
    },
    {
        folder_name: 'folder 002',
        file_name: ['anh 1','anh 2','anh 3','anh 4']
    }
]
```

Thanks you very much

Comment: Don't post your data as an image. Post it as text, in JavaScript syntax. Secondly, you should describe what you have tried and where you got stuck (error, unexpected output, infinite loop, ....)

Comment: Thank you
I have fully uploaded my code, can you help me
My problem is that I don't know how to split the array to get the result like in my post

Comment: When you drafted your question, there were instructions: (1) Summarize the problem (2) Describe what you've tried (3) Show some code. You hardly did (1), and you have not done (2) nor (3).

Comment: I'm sorry
Since I'm new to it, I don't know
I'll withdraw my experience next time
Thank you so much

Comment: Why "next time"? Please edit your question and add what you have tried and which code you used, and what happened (error? infinite loop? unexpected output?)

Answer (score 2):

The short one:

```js
let result = array.reduce((accumulator,c)=>{

       !accumulator.find(w=>w.folder_name == c.folder_name)?
       accumulator.push({folder_name: c.folder_name, file_name: [c.file_name]}):
       accumulator.find(w=>w.folder_name == c.folder_name).file_name.push(c.file_name)    
        
    return accumulator
},[])
```

Using [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function makes it easy and readable. Reduce function iterates first parameter (which is a function) as much as the length of `array`. We pass an empty list as a second parameter to the Reduce function. It is also the `accumulator` parameter. Reduce function updates the list a.k.a `accumulator` in every iteration. It means Reduce returns of the previous iteration's `accumulator` in each one.

e.g: `accumulator.push(5)` will return a list contains the number 5 as the length of `array`, because we pushed the number 5 to the list in every iteration.

The parameter `c` is the current element being processed in the array.

e.g: The first iteration of Reduce gives `array[0]` in the parameter `c`, the second one gives `array[1]`, and so on. In this case, `c` is an object list.

Moreover, we use [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in the function we have passed as a first parameter. Conditional Operator is the short version of the If-else statement.

```
!accumulator.find(w=>w.folder_name == c.folder_name)
```

We search if the list `accumulator` contains an object that has the same key-value with the parameter `c` (which is one of the elements of `array` - depends on the index of iteration).

If we do not find any `folder_name` equals to `c`'s one, we push a new object that contains those values

```
accumulator.push({folder_name: c.folder_name, file_name: [c.file_name]})
```

If we find any `folder_name` equals to `c`'s one, we get this object with the help of `find` and add necessary values to this object

```
accumulator.find(w=>w.folder_name == c.folder_name).file_name.push(c.file_name)
```

In conclusion, after checking every `c` (Current Value) in `accumulator` and adding necessary values to `accumulator` in each iteration, we return `accumulator`. It passes `accumulator` to the next iteration and at the end, it returns `accumulator` itself

Comment: Woooooooooh that's way too small please add a little implementation too it would be much easier for OP ! ( Good answer though )

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data=[{folder_name:"folder 002",file_name:"anh 1.jpg"},{folder_name:"folder 002",file_name:"anh 2.jpg"},{folder_name:"folder 002",file_name:"anh 3.jpg"},{folder_name:"folder 002",file_name:"anh 4.jpg"},{folder_name:"folder 001",file_name:"anh 1.jpg"},{folder_name:"folder 001",file_name:"anh 2.jpg"},{folder_name:"folder 001",file_name:"anh 3.jpg"}];

// Iterate over the data with `reduce`
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
const out = data.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // Grab the folder_name as the key
  const { folder_name: key, file_name } = c;

  // If the key doesn't exist on the accumulator
  // create a new object with a file_name array
  acc[key] = acc[key] || { folder_name: key, file_name: [] };

  // Push the filename into the new object array
  acc[key].file_name.push(file_name);

  // Return the accumulator
  return acc;
}, {});

// Grab the object values (an array) from the
// returned object
console.log(Object.values(out));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it's the best way to imploment this.
But it works!

```js
const input = [
  { folderName: "folder1", fileName: "file11" },
  { folderName: "folder1", fileName: "file12" },
  { folderName: "folder1", fileName: "file13" },
  { folderName: "folder2", fileName: "file21" },
  { folderName: "folder2", fileName: "file22" },
  { folderName: "folder2", fileName: "file23" },
];

const output = [];

const folderNames = [];

input.forEach((item) => {
  if (!folderNames.includes(item.folderName)) folderNames.push(item.folderName);
});
folderNames.forEach((item) => output.push({ folderName: item, fileNames: [] }));

output.forEach((item, index) => {
  const files = input.filter((i) => i.folderName === item.folderName);
  item.fileNames = [...files.map((i) => i.fileName)];
});

console.log(output);
```

Sorry about some change in keys of your object.I tried to write something similar to your object.

Comment: Thank you very much
Thanks for your help, I solved the problem
Wishing you the best of luck in your life

Answer (score 1):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to achieve this :

```
let ans = data.reduce((cum,x)=>{
  let exists = cum.findIndex((a)=>{
    if(a['folder_name'] == x['folder_name'])
      return true;
  });
  if(exists==-1){
    cum.push({
      folder_name : x['folder_name'],
      file_name : [x['file_name']]
    })
  }
  else{
    cum[exists]['file_name'].push(x['file_name']);
  }
  return cum;
},[]);
```

Reduce converts the array to a single value by applying the same function to all elements. The second param `[]` is the initial value to start with.
For each element in the data array, I am checking if the respective folder element exists in the `cum` array. (`cum` array is changing at every iteration.) Now, if it does I am pushing to that elements property or else i am pushing a whole new element in the `cum` array.

Note: The order differs from your expected answer. You can use custom `sort()` to help fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's best implementation but  it works

```
  const images = [{
    folder_name: "folder 001",
    file_name: "ab",
  },
    {
      folder_name: "folder 001",
      file_name: "ab",
    },
    {
      folder_name: "folder 002",
      file_name: "ab",
    }]

  const converted_images = []

  let folders = [];

  images.forEach(img => {
    folders.includes(img.folder_name) ? null: folders.push(img.folder_name)
  })

  folders.forEach(folder => {
    let arr = images.filter(image => image.folder_name === folder)
    let file_name = [];
    arr.forEach(obj => {
      file_name.push(obj.file_name)
    })

    let object = {
      folder_name: folder,
      file_name: file_name
    }

    converted_images.push(object)
  });

  console.log(converted_images)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function out

```js
const splitArray = array => {
  const folders = [];
  let fileName = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const folderName = array[i].folder_name;
    const index = folderName[folderName.length - 1] * 1 - 1;
    if (folders[index] === undefined) {
      fileName = [];
    }
    fileName.push(array[i].file_name);
    folders[index] = {};
    folders[index]['folder_name'] = folderName;

    folders[index]['file_name'] = [...fileName];
  }
  return folders;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let folderNames = [];
data.forEach(each=>{
    if(!folderNames.includes( each["folder_name"])){
    folderNames.push(each["folder_name"]);
});

let image = [];
folderNames.forEach(item=>{
    let fileNames = data.filter((i) => i["folderName"] === item && i["file_name"]);
    let tempObj = {};
    tempObj["folder_name"] = item;
    tempObj["file_name"] = fileNames;
    image.push(tempObj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make a map of the folders?
So it would look like this:

```
const images = {
    "folder 001": {
        "folder_names": [
            "anh 1",
            "anh 2",
            "anh 3"
        ]
    },
    "folder 002": {
        "folder_names": [
            "anh 1",
            "anh 2",
            "anh 3",
            "anh 4"
        ]
    }
}
```

The spacing is a bit weird because I actually made that, then did stringify with tabs.

Anyways, the way you'd want to do that is

```
let images = {};
for(let row of database){
    if(row["folder_name"] != undefined){
        if(images[row["folder_name"]] == undefined){
            images[row["folder_name"]] = {};
            images[row["folder_name"]].file_names = [];
        }
    }
    images[row["folder_name"]].file_names.concat(row["file_name"]);
}
```